# Contribution of each eigenspace's error to the loss

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, optimization

I'm reading [Why momentum really works](https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/) and I have a problem with a piece of math in part related to gradient descent analysis.

Article's author analyzes the gradient descent on the simplest nontrivial problem: quadratic form with $A$ being symmetric and invertible:
$$
f(w) = \frac{1}{2} w^TAw - b^Tw, \quad w \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
The problem has optimal solution at $w^* = A^{-1}b$. We approach it though using gradient descent:
$$
w^{k+1} = w^k - \alpha (Aw^k - b).
$$
If we change the basis for $w^k = Qx^k + w^*$, where $Q$ is the matrix of $A$'s eigenvectors ($A = Q \Lambda Q^T$), we soon realize that:
$$
w^k - w^* = Qx^k = \sum_i^n x_i^0 (1 - \alpha \lambda_i)^k q_i.
$$
So we get the error at $k$-th iteration of gradient descent.

Then, in *Decomposing the Error* section, the author visualizes how error components contribute to the loss. To do so he writes the contributions of each eigenspace's error to the loss:
$$
f(w^k) - f(w^*) = \sum(1 - \alpha \lambda_i)^{2k} \lambda_i [x_i^0]^2.
$$
How did he get that? I tried using least squares, so I assumed $d=w^k - w^*$ and took the norm ($d^Td)$ but I did get:
$$
\sum(1 - \alpha \lambda_i)^{2k} [x_i^0]^2 [q_i]^2.
$$
Do I even approach it in the right way?

Comment: @whuber this question is not a duplication. The linked question explains $w^k - w^\star$ while this one asks about $f(w^k) - f(w^\star)$

Comment: the result can be derived as following: $f(w) - f(w^\star) = \\
\frac{1}{2} w^TAw - b^Tw - \frac{1}{2} [w^\star]^TAw^\star + b^Tw^\star) = \\
\frac{1}{2} (w^TAw - 2(Aw^\star)^Tw - [w^\star]^TAw^\star + 2(Aw^\star)^Tw^\star) = \\
\frac{1}{2} (w^TAw - 2[w^\star]^TAw + [w^\star]^TAw^\star) = \\
\frac{1}{2} (w^TA(w - w^\star) - [w^\star]^TA(w - w^\star)) = \\
\frac{1}{2} (w - w^\star)^TA(w - w^\star) = \\
\frac{1}{2} (w - w^\star)^TQ\Lambda Q^T(w - w^\star) = \\
\frac{1}{2} x^T \Lambda x = \\
\frac{1}{2} \sum_i^n (1-\alpha\lambda_i)^{2k}\lambda_i[x_i^0]^2$

Comment: Simpler answer: in the eigenbasis, $f$ is the sum of squares, *QED.*